# Python writing bytes through socket

Tags: python

I want to write a byte (0-255) over a socket but I can't figure out how to.

`socket.send( str( unichr( byte ) ) )` works for 0-128 then gives a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Is there anyway to write a byte over a socket? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just write the byte to the socket, and encode it to string at the receiving end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a normal bytestring.

```
socket.send('\xa5')
socket.send('Hello, world!')
```

Or, `chr()`.

```
socket.send(chr(0xa5))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not actually the socket that is giving the error it is the str function:

```
>>> str(unichr(200))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc8' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> unicode(unichr(200))
u'\xc8'
```

Try sending that instead.

Comment: Bytes should be sent through a socket, not text.